# iPhone just keeps offloading SoundCloud app even though it is used heavilly

Tags: iphone, ios

My question is related to peculiar behavior of my iPhone, as suggested in the title.

Offloading means deleting the app from the phone, however data remains, so after user installs it back from appstore, it just works in continuity from before the deletion of the app. Operating System on iOS allows automatic offloading of apps, which were not used much, to save memory/space.

Yes my iPhone is full, and I allowed offloading of unused apps. (and I really need this). ... it makes sense that iOS wants to offload some app, but why SounCloud? Many other apps are still present, untouched.

The strange thing is, that SoundCloud is probably the most used app on my phone, and it would be just too much, if it was offloaded/deleted even ones. Even that would not make sense. However, it just keeps be deleted over and over on regular basis. I have to reinstall the app in quite unexpected situations if I want listen to music again. Often in situations without strong data signal.

I didn't notice that there would be any other apps, which would be offloaded/deleted prematurely like this. It seems to me, that otherwise only apps which I did not use for a long time are targeted by the system and offloaded.

In the case of Soundcloud - I use it kind of at least for few hours a day. Often I can let it run from the morning to the night nonstop. Everyday! Still - after being in subway for an hour (not data signal - not using anything, or after watching YouTube for few hours - and bang! Souncloud is gone! Again! All that the system apparently needs to decide, that my SoundCloud is unused to delete it is few hours of me doing something else and it targets SounCloud preferentially and deletes it!

My question is actually double:

1) First, I just really want to stop offloading this particular application (while keeping the system decide what other app was not used lately and let it automatically offload that) .. if there exist any more specific setting allowing me to make an exception for an app, that I wish the particular app to not be offloaded, I would love to use it.

2) Second, I am just amused and curious, why that particular app might be targeted in the first place? Does not make sense at all! It even feels as if iOS is picking on SoundCloud or something. Any reasons?

I have iPhone SE and always with the latest OS (and behavior is the same regardless on the version of iOS). I have 32 GB of memory space and it is always close to be full. ... And I keep listening something on earphones non-stop, either music on SoundCloud, or some podcast or YouTube.

(I would suggest tags I cannot add: SoundCloud and Offloading)

Answer (score 1):

I am actually using this 'Offload' feature for a long time and I took care of my apps about whether they are still ready to use...
But..
I have never seen the situation that you've faced. It's interesting for iPhone to execute Offload App command such an app which is in being used constantly.

My advice you to delete the app without offload and backup, directly erase the app, then install again and start from zero to use. I hope it DOES work in time!

Comment: Thank You I will try that. Never thought about deleting it for real. It is actully without damage in the case of SoundClound .. to my knowledge this particular app does not need any special data on site, except my login. I will try that.

Comment: It still does that ... but it seem to be reduced to a degree. Anyway I need iphone with bigger internal memory.... this is terrible experience.